# Save received data to the order from an external delivery service in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, curl, woocommerce, orders

How to save the order id from delivery service in metadata?

```
    add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_delivery');
    function send_order_to_delivery( $order_id ){
        // Send data
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.axample.com/api/index.php?new_order");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $json = '$result';

        $delivery_order_id = json_decode($json)->order_id;

        if ( ! empty( $_POST['delivery_order_id'] ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_order_id', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['delivery_order_id'] ) );
        }
    }
```

When I send the order to an external delivery service, I get the answer `echo $result;` -

```
{"result":"success","order_id":100888,"order_number":10}
```

Need save `"order_id":100888`for this new order.

Comment: print_r($result); show: {"result":"success","order_id":7294718,"order_number":7} I realized that need to use json_decode(). foreach - wrong. Not sure about save meta data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following instead

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'send_order_to_delivery');
function send_order_to_delivery( $order_id ){
    // Send data
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://app.axample.com/api/index.php?new_order");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $decoded = (array) json_decode($result);

    // Test output
    if( isset($decoded['result']) && $decoded['result'] == 'success'  && isset($decoded['order_id']) && !empty($decoded['order_id']) ){
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'delivery_order_id', esc_attr( $decoded['order_id'] ) );
    } 
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much!