# Add custom meta data to admin order edit pages in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

When I send the order to an external delivery service (API), I get the answer:
`$delivery_order_id = '100678'`.
[In this matter, these data are stored in metadata.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51061953/save-received-data-to-the-order-from-an-external-delivery-service-in-woocommerce/51068586#51068586)

How to display this value in the admin panel Woocommerce?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using dedicated hooks like `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details` this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_order_details', 'admin_order_display_delivery_order_id', 60, 1 );
function admin_order_display_delivery_order_id( $order ){

    $delivery_order_id = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), 'delivery_order_id', true );

    $delivery_id = ! empty( $delivery_order_id ) ? $delivery_order_id : '<span style="color:red">' .__('Not yet.') . '</span>';
    echo '<br clear="all"><p><strong>'.__('Delivery Order Id').':</strong> ' . $delivery_id . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

As LoicTheAztec said you can put any meta anywhere you want: just take it from 'get_post_meta...' and send to any block using your output function in add_action with name like  'woocommerce_admin_order_data...'

Comment: This should be a comment